# Can you upload remote files with intern leadfoot

Tags: intern, leadfoot

I'm testing a file upload feature and trying to upload remote files(e.g. https://s3.amazonaws.com/some_dir/some_file). Using type() throws an error stating the path is not absolute. Is this supported by intern? If yes, how should it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leadfoot handles file uploads like this:

1. The test calls `type` on a file input element with the local (to Intern) path of a file. This file must exist on the system running Intern. You can get an absolute path to it by using `require.toUrl` (e.g., `element.type(require.toUrl('./someFile.txt'))`).
2. Leadfoot silently uploads the file to the remote Selenium/WebDriver server and determines its path on the remote system.
3. Leadfoot calls `sendKeys` on the input element using the path of the newly uploaded file on the remote server.

The end goal is for the remote browser to be able to select a file for a file input and send it somewhere. For that to work, the file must exist on the remote system (the one running the browser being tested).

Comment: I was able to get this working in Chrome, but it doesn't work in Firefox. Have you encountered issues with file uploads in Firefox?