# How can I test an input type="file" with Browserstack

Tags: javascript, html, intern, browserstack

So, I've been trying to test an input type="file" with Browserstack and Intern.js, but I keep getting a "File not found" error because Browserstack searches for the file in my computer.

I know that Browserstack has Upload/Download capabilities, but from their documentation I didn't quite get how to use it.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28430547/file-upload-in-intern-js

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, because the problem is not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues doesn't seem to be different. Assuming that you get 'File not found' error on your test page, I believe that your type command is simply sending the keys to remote browser's element.

For an input element of type '**file**', **type** command should first upload the file from your local machine to the remote machine and then transparently upload to your test page. If this is not working then mostly your element is not of type '**file**' or the version of intern you are using does not support remote upload/has bug.

According to me it should fail locally as well, provided you have **selenium standalone server and webdriver** setup which uses remotewebdriver.

Extract from 'https://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/module-leadfoot_Command.html#type' (shared by jason0x43)

---

*Since 1.5, if the WebDriver server supports remote file uploads, and you type a path to a file on your local computer, that file will be transparently uploaded to the remote server and the remote filename will be typed instead. If you do not want to upload local files, use leadfoot/Session#pressKeys instead.*

---

**Solution** (worked for me):

---

Sample code:

```
function () {
      return this.remote
        .get(require.toUrl('http://www.fileconvoy.com/'))
        .findById('upfile_0')
          // .type('C:\\Users\\hello\\Desktop\\documents\\doc-sample1.doc')
          .type("//tmp//upload.log")
          .end()
        .findById('readTermsOfUse').click().end()
        .findById('upload_button').click().end()
        .sleep(5000)
    }
```

### ----------

conf.js

```
  capabilities: {
    fixSessionCapabilities: true,
    remoteFiles: true,
    .
    .
    .
  },
```

---

Comment: Hey Sanket, thanks for the detailed answer. I just updated all packages, but still it doesn't work. I contacted Browserstack and they said I should just add these two lines to the top of my tests: `var remote = require('selenium-webdriver/remote'); driver.setFileDetector(new remote.FileDetector); `. But I don't know how to apply this, since I'm using Intern.js. From this snippet of Leadfoot's documentation, it seems that it should already be doing that.

Comment: My setup : Node - v6.9.4, NPM - 4.1.1, intern - 3.4.6, leadfoot - 1.7.4  
 Simply using **type** didnt work in this setup.    Further referring to  https://github.com/theintern/leadfoot/issues/51#issuecomment-135939441 explains that there were some fixes made which changed the behaviour of **type**. I tried adding these two capabilities and **type** command just worked out of the box for local files. **fixSessionCapabilities: true** and **remoteFiles: true**

Comment: Sanket! Thank you! That worked, actually I just changed fixSessonCapabilities to true and put the remoteFiles in the conf.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the path to a file on your local system into the input using the [`type`](https://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/module-leadfoot_Command.html#type) method. Intern will upload the file to the remote system and then select the newly uploaded file in the remote browser's file input.

```
return remote
    .findElementById('file-input')
    .type('/tmp/somefile.txt') <-- Path on the local system
```

Comment: That's how it's written right now and it works locally. But it doesn't work in Browserstack, it doesn't upload anything to the remote system it just returns a "File not found" error, because the remote system doesn't have access to my local file system.

Comment: So, my problem is the same as this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37217884/can-you-upload-remote-files-with-intern-leadfoot . I did what you said there, but still it doesn't work for Firefox and Chrome.